# Flutter: Hero animation in Same Screen

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I'm trying to make a dynamic animation described in the mockup above. What I need is:

While the user clicks on a list item. It will go up. How can I do that?

```
 Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                ReusableCard(
                    colour: Colors.green,
                    cardChild: Wrap(
                      alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
                      spacing: -23,
                      runSpacing: -2,
                      children: List<Widget>.generate(
                        widget.mycards.length,
                        (int index) {
                          return GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              cardBrain.kartat(widget.mycards[index].id,
                                  widget.mycards[index].deger);
                            },
                            child: Image(
                              height: 116,
                              image: AssetImage(
                                '${widget.mycards[index].image}',//IT MUST GO UP (in The other expanded widget)
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    )),
              ],
            ),),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hero Animation of flutter is designed for the animation between 2 pages from flutter website. The nearest package that I have found is the [local_hero](https://pub.dev/packages/local_hero) package.
If the animation is not too complicated, I think you can also do it with the flutter animation.